# get user type from res.users in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

i am trying to get user type from res.users in odoo12.
i did not found a field named ***sel_groups_1_9_10*** 
here is my code,

```
current_user = fields.Many2one('res.users','Current User', default=lambda self: self.env.uid)
@api.multi
    def add_followers(self):    
        print(self.current_user.sel_groups_1_9_10)
```

it generates an error: object res.users has no attribute sel_groups_1_9_10.

how can i get user type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

milan vala

It is not any field that you can access. It is the group can be classified along with the user of which type.
You can check `group` with this `has_group` like this :

```
    self.env.user.has_group('base.group_user') # Check for Internal User
    self.env.user.has_group('base.group_portal') # Check for Portal User
    self.env.user.has_group('base.group_public') # Check for Public User
```